# Azure Data Factory Data Flow: how to filter input column with multiple values

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What I am trying to do is basically something that emulates SQL WHERE IN CLAUSE in a data flow. I want to pass comma separated string of values into my data flow, i.e ptf_proc_link_id = "A, B, C".

[image]

Inside of the data flow, I want to use those values, to filter one of my input columns:

[image]

It would be equal to writing in SQL SELECT * FROM my_delta_table where ptf_proc_link_id in (A, B, C).

However, data flow documentation only hints that I can filter single values i.e ptf_proc_link_id = A. I have tried to use intersect, but then both parameters needs to be arrays, and in my case one of them is a column. I could do something like ptf_proc_link_id = A OR ptf_proc_link_id = B OR ptf_proc_link_id = C, but I never know how many input values I would have, so I cannot hardcode it.

It seems like a very simple use case for a data flow, so I would be really thankful if someone could explain me what the correct approach would be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in()` function in ADF data flow to filter multiple values.

Syntax:
`in(array of items,item to find)`

- I tried to repro this with sample input data.

| key | class | name | mark | DOB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Arjuna | 50 | 1/2/2015 |
| 2 | 1 | Basanta | 47 | 5/1/2015 |
| 3 | 1 | Subala | 54 | 5/6/2015 |
| 4 | 2 | Gandharva | 60 | 1/2/2014 |
| 5 | 2 | Ujjvala | 55 | 9/2/2014 |
| 6 | 2 | Sanadhana | 64 | 1/12/2014 |
| 7 | 3 | Sridama | 75 | 1/2/2013 |
| 8 | 3 | Sudama | 80 | 13/12/2013 |
| 9 | 3 | Vasu | 81 | 1/12/2013 |

[image]
img:1 Source data preview.

- I tried to filter the records with key=2,4,6
- Filter condition can be given as
  `in(['2','4','6'], key)`  or
  `in(array('2','4','6'), key)`
  [image]
  img:2 Filter condition settings
- **Output data of the filter Transformation:**

[image]
img:3 Filter Transformation data preview

- You can also create a dataflow parameter of array type and give that parameter in the filter condition of filter transformation.
  [image]
  img: 4 dataflow parameters
- Filter condition while using parameter will be `in($parameter1,key)`

Reference: [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#in) on `data flow expression - in`

Answer (score 0):

You always could declare your variables in your query and equal these to a ADF variable or parameter.For example, in the lookup activity or Query in CopyActivity you could set these:
i.e:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON
--SET FMTONLY OFF

DECLARE 

    @frdate DATETIME = @{variables('FromDate')}, -- created in ADF
    @todate DATETIME = @{variables('ToDate')}; -- created in pipeline

select 1
FROM table c
where
c.var_1 in (@{pipeline().parameters.parameter1}) -- Create the parameter in ADF
AND c.DateTime between @frdate and @todate
```